# linq join query for getting one record from 2nd table

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I Have two table

table 1

```
ID  name

1   a
2   b
3   c
```

table 2

```
id  date

1   4/4/2016
1   4/5/2016
2   6/6/2016
3   7/7/2016
3   7/8/2016
```

expected result

```
id  name    date    
1   a       4/4/2016    
2   b       6/6/2016    
3   c       7/7/2016
```

Here I tried some query its returning me the full records but I need only the smaller date from the table 2 can any one let me know how can I get the query for the same.

```
 from p in table1 join n in  table2 on p.Id equals n.Id  select new list(){ ID=p.ID, name=p.Name, date=n.date}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just turn your join into [group join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) and take the min date from each related group:

```
from p in table1
join n in table2 on p.Id equals n.Id into g
select new list() { ID = p.ID, name = p.Name, date = g.Min(n => n.date) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var result =
    table1
        .Select(x =>
            new
            {
                ID = x.ID,
                Name = x.Name,
                Date =
                    table2.Where(y => y.ID == x.ID)
                        .OrderBy(y => y.Date)
                        .Select(y => y.Date)
                        .FirstOrDefault()
            })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: @ Yacoub Massad ,thanks for you time. one quick question plz. How can I achieve the same, if I have 3 or more join conditions .

Comment: It depends. I suggest you create another question with enough details for that.

Comment: By the way, is this a database query? Or are these tables in memory? How large are the tables. Please note that the solution I provided might not be the best in terms of performance.